# Create an Update Query using Union Function?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, union

I have an Excel table that I import to an Access 2010 database table. The only problem is the data for one field (Health Plan) is not consistent with what we currently use in our database. For example the data that is being imported shows "GA" vs what it should be, "CHC - GEORGIA". I'm able to make a simple Update query for changing ONE at a time, but I have 15+ states that need to be changed. This is what I was shooting for in combining these into one query:

```
UPDATE [Dan - CSF Quotes] SET [Dan - CSF Quotes].[Health Plan] = "HEALTHAMERICA And HEALTHASSURANCE"
WHERE ((([Dan - CSF Quotes].[Health Plan])="PA"))

UNION 

UPDATE [Dan - CSF Quotes] SET [Dan - CSF Quotes].[Health Plan] = "CHC - GEORGIA"
WHERE ((([Dan - CSF Quotes].[Health Plan])="GA"));

.
.
.
etc
```

Is there any easy way to change/update the values to this one field?

Comment: UNION is for connecting multiple SELECT results into one. You can't use it for UPDATE. Just simply use multiple UPDATE statements one after another.

Comment: THanks for the info. I'm fairly new and creating queries and knew that what I had above wouldn't work, more for illustrative purposes to get my "point across". Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SWITCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) to apply different conditions to a single update statement:

```
UPDATE [Dan - CSF Quotes] 
SET [Health Plan] = SWITCH
                    (   [Health Plan] = "GA", "CHC - GEORGIA",
                        [Health Plan] = "PA", "HEALTHAMERICA And HEALTHASSURANCE"
                    )
WHERE [Health Plan] IN ("GA", "PA");
```

Comment: Thank You! It looks like this is working. I think there is a limit on how many lines I can "switch", but from what I've added so far, it is indeed working.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 15+ search/replace pairs, consider storing them in a separate table such as the *HealthPlanReplacements* sample table below.  Then you can use an `UPDATE` query which joins the replacements table to your primary data table.

This query does what I think you want:

```sql
UPDATE [Dan - CSF Quotes] AS dq
    INNER JOIN HealthPlanReplacements AS hpr
    ON dq.[Health Plan] = hpr.search_plan
SET dq.[Health Plan] = [hpr].[replace_plan];
```

And this is the *HealthPlanReplacements* table I used to test that query in Access 2007:

```
search_plan replace_plan
----------- ---------------------------------
GA          CHC - GEORGIA
PA          HEALTHAMERICA And HEALTHASSURANCE
```